# DisplayPort stops working when HDMI is plugged in

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I am trying to connect 2 monitors to my desktop pc. The first monitor is connected through a DisplayPort cable and the second through an HDMI one. The first monitor works just fine until plugging the HDMI cable for the second monitor. Hence, only the second monitor is working. It seems like the first monitor remains on but nothing is displayed.
Is there any solution ?
here is the output of the lspci -v command :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 25
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: fc800000-fc8fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=28, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc6fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=29, subordinate=29, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fb000000-fc0fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000e1ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=2a, subordinate=2a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: fc200000-fc4fffff [size=3M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=2b, subordinate=2b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: fc700000-fc7fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 2263 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 2263
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 58, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fc800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at fc6a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 57
    Memory at fc680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at fc600000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=20, subordinate=28, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc5fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=25, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc5fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=26, subordinate=26, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=27, subordinate=27, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=28, subordinate=28, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fc504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

29:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2484 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Palit Microsystems Inc. Device 2484
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 85
    Memory at fb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

29:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Palit Microsystems Inc. Device 2484
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 82
    Memory at fc080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

2a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2a:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 78
    Memory at fc300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at fc400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp

2a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at fc200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

2b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2b:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
    Memory at fc708000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

2b:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 84
    Memory at fc700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

and the output of the xrandr command :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1168, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+88 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.93    59.94  
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 165.00   144.00   119.98   119.88    59.94    50.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768     119.99    99.97    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600      119.97    99.66    75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480      119.52    99.77    75.00    72.81    59.93    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you update your question to include the output of `lspci -v`? This will show information about your video card, making it easier to offer a possible solution 

Comment: I just added the output of lspci -v and xrandr command. thank you

Comment: It looks like you may not have the right video drivers installed. Are you using an Nvidia RTX3070? Could you update your question to include the output of `nvidia-smi`? This will show the version that's being used. You may need version 455.38 (or newer) to get the most from your card.

Comment: I am indeed using an NVIDIA 3070, the driver version, is 455.45.01, which is (i suppose) newer than the 455.38 version ?

Comment: I had this with a Dell monitor - a bit of googling showed it was an unfixable  known issue with the monitor itself (sorry I don't have access to the model number at the moment). Eventually I just avoided the problem by using a second HDMI port and an HDMI to Display Port adapter cable.

Comment: From what I can see with spec sheets, the RTX3070 has one HDMI port and 3 DisplayPorts. Your `xrandr` is showing the one HDMI plus *five* DPs. I've seen this on notebooks that use DP++ so that a pair of ports (usually USB-C) are used *either* as a single HDMI or single DisplayPort. If the driver for the RTX3070 is doing something similar, then you may not be able to use DP-0 and HDMI-0 at the same time. Have you tried plugging the DP monitor into a different port?

Comment: Yes I tried all the 3 different DP that are available, none of them is working. The screen is detected and is on but nothing is displayed